# Can cancellation token be used at tasks method within?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I've just started working with tasks and I've come to some things I don't quite understand about calling methods within the task. I have started a new task like this:

```
var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = ts.Token;

Task.Run(() => Control(), token);


void Control() 
{
     while(!token.IsCancellationRequested) 
     {
          token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

          switch(ENUM) 
          {

               case SOMETHING:

                 StartSomething();
               break;

          }


          Task.Delay(50, token).wait();
     }
 }
```

Now I don't understand the behavior of `StartSomething()` once token has been cancelled. What if `StartSomething()` as well contains a while loop, can I as well use?

```
!token.IsCancellationRequested
```

and

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

As well, if the Cancellation exception is being thrown inside that `StartSomething()` loop, will it instantly cancel task?

Comment: Ideally you want to pass `token` onto anything which may take some time, possibly `StartSomething()` and periodically check the token for cancellation.

Comment: Thank you! If the task gets cancelled at StartSomething() method, will that instantly cancel task, or first return to Control() loop and then do?

Comment: @user2818626 it throws an exception that would bubble up through `Control`. As long as you don't catch it the task will be cancelled.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now :) Another thing, if StartSomething() has any long-running sleeps, should there instead be used "Task.Delay(50, token).wait()" instead Thread.Sleep(ms)? And does that on cancellation behave as thrown exception?

Comment: @user2818626 yes, and yes. Async is almost always better than blocking synchronously.

Comment: @user2818626 I missed the `Wait`. It's actually better to use async-await: `await Task.Delay(50, token);`.

Comment: But what if I actually want it to wait and not to proceed, until the delay is completed?

Comment: @user2818626 That's what await does. It waits, just asynchronously. The code after that line will not continue running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily pass the same token onto `StartSomething` and exceptions from it will bubble up to `Control` and cancel the task. If you don't then it will keep running even if the CancellationToken`was cancelled until it returns control to`Control` that observes the token:

```
void StartSomething(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // Will cancel the task.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though that `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` will raise exception and the task will be canceled while `!token.IsCancellationRequested` will simply complete the task without marking it as canceled.

Comment: Thank you! It all makes sense now :)